# Can't get jhipster (6.3.1) generated application running on IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, jhipster

I'm trying to get my `JHipster 6.3.1` generated application running in `IE 11` but keep on getting one **error** after another. Depending on which imports I use in `polyfill.ts` I get anything from 'Symbol' is undefined" to a plain "Syntax error" and sometimes no particular error at all, just a page with the generic JHipster

> An error has occurred :-(

I've tried different combinations of `polyfills` and `tsconfig.json` settings. I've installed the recommended `polyfills` as per angular 8 docs, but it seems that `jhipsters angular != standard angular` as all pure `angular 8` documentation regarding `IE11` were unhelpful.

I know `IE 11` is not supported anymore by `JHipster`, but since Angular has specific instructions on using `polyfills` and differential loading to get it working, I expected (assumed) it would be a fairly straight forward fix.

Comment: Since you are using angular 8, please refer to [my reply in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362323/angular-8-project-not-working-in-microsoft-edge-and-ie11) to configure your application to use "es5" target (it is better to use the second method), then using the `ng serve --configuration es5` command to run your application.

Comment: I've tried target "es5". Didn't work. There are many more tutorials on how angular 8 can be made to cooperate with IE 11 and that is not my problem. The problem seems to be the way JHipster generates the Angular 8 content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10184#issuecomment-541650501), I managed to do it the following way.

First, add those `package.json` dependencies: `@babel/core`, `@babel/preset-env` and `babel-loader`:

```sh
yarn add @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-loader --exact --dev
```

(tested with the following versions:

```
    "@babel/core": "7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
```

)

Now add the following lines at the top of `src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts`:

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
```

In `webpack/webpack.common.js`, after

```js
            {
                test: /manifest.webapp$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'manifest.webapp'
                }
            },
```

add the following lines:

```js
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                    "presets": [
                      [
                        "@babel/preset-env",
                        {
                          "targets": {
                            "firefox": "60",
                            "ie": "11"
                          },
                          "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                          "corejs": 3
                        }
                      ]
                    ]
                  }
                },
                exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime|core-js/,
              },
```

And finally, change `target` to `es5` in `tsconfig.json` & `tsconfig-aot.json`.

Here is my full test:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /dev/shm/myproject
cd /dev/shm/
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
mkdir /dev/shm/m2cache /dev/shm/yarncache
sudo tee myproject.jdl <<EOF
application {
    config {
        baseName MyProject
        clientPackageManager yarn
        jhiPrefix mp
        enableTranslation false
        languages [fr]
        nativeLanguage fr
        packageName com.mycompany.myproject
        prodDatabaseType postgresql
        skipUserManagement true
    }
    entities *
}

entity MyEntity {
    label String
}
EOF
JHIPSTER_VERSION=v6.3.1
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 . /dev/shm/m2cache /dev/shm/yarncache
docker run -it --rm --name jhipster -v "$(pwd):/home/jhipster/app" -v /dev/shm/m2cache:/home/jhipster/.m2 -v /dev/shm/yarncache:/home/jhipster/.cache/yarn -v "$HOME/.gitconfig:/home/jhipster/.gitconfig:ro" jhipster/jhipster:$JHIPSTER_VERSION jhipster import-jdl ./myproject.jdl --force

# WAIT FOR THE APPLICATION TO BE GENERATED

docker run -it --rm --name jhipster -v "$(pwd):/home/jhipster/app" -v /dev/shm/m2cache:/home/jhipster/.m2 -v /dev/shm/yarncache:/home/jhipster/.cache/yarn -p 9000:9000 -p 8080:8080 jhipster/jhipster:$JHIPSTER_VERSION yarn add @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-loader --exact --dev

# WAIT FOR THE YARN COMMAND TO END

echo "
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

$(cat src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts)
" | sudo -u '#1000' tee src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts

cat > /dev/shm/webpack.patch <<EOF
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                    "presets": [
                      [
                        "@babel/preset-env",
                        {
                          "targets": {
                            "firefox": "60",
                            "ie": "11"
                          },
                          "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                          "corejs": 3
                        }
                      ]
                    ]
                  }
                },
                exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime|core-js/,
            },
EOF
sudo -u '#1000' sed -i $'/Ignore warnings about System.import in Angular/{e cat /dev/shm/webpack.patch\n}' webpack/webpack.common.js

for FILE in tsconfig.json tsconfig-aot.json; do
  sudo -u '#1000' sed -i 's/"target": "es6"/"target": "es5"/' $FILE
done

docker run -it --rm --name jhipster -v "$(pwd):/home/jhipster/app" -v /dev/shm/m2cache:/home/jhipster/.m2 -v /dev/shm/yarncache:/home/jhipster/.cache/yarn -p 9000:9000 -p 8080:8080 jhipster/jhipster:$JHIPSTER_VERSION bash -c "./mvnw & yarn start --host 0.0.0.0"
```

Thanks to https://www.thebasement.be/working-with-babel-7-and-webpack/ , https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage and https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/514#issuecomment-523524472 for the hints!

Comment: Had the same problem, worked like a charm, thanks. Since this solution allows using the latest core-js version, it should be the recommended solution...

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working. What I did was I generated an Angular application with the ng CLI from an older Angular. I compared `tsconfig.json`, `package.json` and `polyfills.ts` and used the 'older' settings for the JHipster generated one. This gave me the following changes:

Lowered versions in `package.json` for:

- `core-js` from `3.1.3` to `^2.4.1`
- `zone-js` from `0.9.1` to `^0.7.2`

In `tsfconfig.json`:

```
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es6",
```

and

```
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
```

and finally `polyfills.ts`

```
    import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
    import 'core-js/es6/object';
    import 'core-js/es6/function';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
    import 'core-js/es6/number';
    import 'core-js/es6/math';
    import 'core-js/es6/string';
    import 'core-js/es6/date';
    import 'core-js/es6/array';
    import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
    import 'core-js/es6/map';
    import 'core-js/es6/set';
    import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
    import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
    import 'core-js/es7/array';
    import 'core-js/es7/object';
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js';
    require('../manifest.webapp');
```

These changes give me a working application in IE11, but only with a `prod` build.